# How to rapidly develop Windows applications that don't depend on other runtimes?

Tags: windows, rad

I'm a C# developer and I see how .NET makes developing Windows applications easier. Type-safety, memory management and a great IDE are but a few things that make developing .NET applications a breeze. Unfortunately these applications require the user to install .NET framework before they install the application itself. This can confuse the users and scare away potential customers.

Is there any other development environment that would allow one to develop Windows applications as easily as in C#, but without the requirement to install other runtimes beforehand?

Answer (score 3):

Embarcadero Delphi is another good candidate http://www.codegear.com/products/delphi

Comment: Does it support automatic memory management (aka garbage collection)? Also - there is a free edition called "TurboDelphi". How good is that?

Comment: Respectively no, and fine.

You didn't specify GC as a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

There also is a free multiplatform Delphi-alike, Lazarus, see http://lazarus.freepascal.org 
less polished but free and quite powerful. (source code compatible to Delphi to a very high degree)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [RealBasic](http://www.realsoftware.com/realbasic/) yet?